# SPA using Laravel 5.8 / Vue - auth() returns token true instead of token value

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, jwt

I'm creating a SPA using Laravel 5.8 and VUE and I'm using JWT to Authenticate by a token.

The authentications work but it returns true as the value instead of the token value. I think to have corrupted my config and I'm not able to fix it again.

My login method is:

```
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials, false)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

         return $token;
     }
```

The result is "true" but I need the JWT value.

Some few steps back:

I'm using: **tymon/jwt-auth**

**the Auth**:

```
function auth($guard = null)
{
    if (is_null($guard)) {
        return app(AuthFactory::class);
    }

    return app(AuthFactory::class)->guard($guard);
}
```

**the config/auth.php**

```
  'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Any suggetsion to check my config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `JWTAuth` facade provided by the package:

```
        if (! $token = \JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return Response::json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }
```

Comment: Thiago can you help me on this task to be able to serve API only to authenticated users? I'm not sure to create a Route::middleware('auth:api') in route or a check into the controller. In any case, can you help me to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can use **guard('api')** or **guard('users')** method, since you have multiple guards

```php
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    if (!$token = auth()->guard('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
         return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }
    
    return $token;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use
auth()->attempt($credentials);
or
Auth::attempt($credentials);

it will return True, so use JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)

```
use PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
   if (!($token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials))) {
       return "error - unauthorised";
   }
return $token;
```

it will help you to get both web session and api jwt token.